# Fill a formula down without dragging in Excel for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anybody know the keyboard shortcuts or menu commands to fill a formula down *without* dragging? I'm using Excel for Mac 2011 on a MacBook.

I've got a spreadsheet like this pattern but for like 5000 rows:

```
A, B, C, D
5, 1, 3   =SUM(A1:C1)
3, 2, 4
...
```

I know how to hover over D1 and get the handle and drag down, but there must be an easier way.

There are a billion tips online but I'm not finding any that work.

FWIW, Macbook has some exceptions to shortcut key rules, so that's probably why, I guess.

But anyhow, anyone know how to do this?

PS: I would have thought "fill series" would be a choice but no. Here's a picture.

[image: A picture]

Comment: In windows, I double click the box in the bottom right of the cell to auto fill, may work on mac too.

Comment: Hey bingo!  It works.  Thanks! Put it as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: According to [Mac Excel Control Shift RIght Arrow](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90350/mac-excel-control-shift-right-arrow), you might be able to use Fn+Shift+Alt+down arrow to select the appropriate cells, in case that is any use (saves scrolling to the last cell).

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, because it specifically asks about key shortcuts on a Mac, whereas the other post details key shortcuts in Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double click the box on the bottom right of the cell with the formula, as shown in your screenshot. It will fill the formula until it finds a blank row.

Comment: If anyone else is struggling with this filling the whole way down, the column has to be right next to a column with data so it knows how far down to fill. I was trying to fill a formula in a column with a few rows of empty cells between it and the filled data, and it wasn't working.